# Extracting Date from File Where File Name Is Variable

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a series of files that I am attempting to parse the date out of the file name. Here is an example of the files that I am currently trying to parse:

```
AC SCR063_6.8.15.xlsx
AC SCR064_6.22.15_REVISED.xlsx
AccentCare July 2015 Rent Report 06.26.15 Final.xlsx
AccentCare June 2015 Rent Report 05.26.15 Final.xlsx
```

In these files, the date will most likely always be in a format of dd.mm.yy or dd.mm.yyyy. I've tried to devise a regex expression to match these dates within the string and I've gotten as far as:

```
 ^(\d{1,2})\.(\d{1,2})\.(\d{2,4})$
```

But due to the variability in the file name and my limited knowledge of regex, I am not sure what else I need to do in order to get this regex to match all of these file name cases. Do I need to create an optional capture group before the date portion of the regex to match anything proceeding it and an optional capture group after it as well to  exclude the Final.xlsx or the _REVISED.xlsx etc?

EDIT: I should also note these filenames would also have the proceeding pathing information within the string I would be evaluating, although I am sure I could just get the straight filename another way if it would be easier to evaluate the string that way.

EDIT 2: Desired output would be 6.8.15 or 06.26.15 etc, just the date portion that is in dd.mm.yy format. That way I could cast it to a date time within my application.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Fyi, your format isn't `dd.mm.yyyy.` but `MM.dd.yyyy.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the allowed formats are `M.d.yyyy`and  `M.d.yy`(not `dd.mm.yyyy` as stated), i would use `DateTime.TryParseExact`. For example with this LINQ query:

```
var fileNames = new string[] { "AC SCR063_6.8.15.xlsx", "AC SCR064_6.22.15_REVISED.xlsx", "AccentCare July 2015 Rent Report 06.26.15 Final.xlsx", "AccentCare June 2015 Rent Report 05.26.15 Final.xlsx" };
string[] allowedFormats = { "M.d.yyyy", "M.d.yy" };
DateTime[] dates = fileNames
    .Select(fn => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fn).Split(' ', '_'))
    .Select(arr => arr.Select(s => s.TryGetDateTime(null, allowedFormats))
                      .FirstOrDefault(dt => dt.HasValue))
    .Where(nullableDate => nullableDate.HasValue)
    .Select(nullableDate => nullableDate.Value)
    .ToArray();
```

which uses this handy extension method to parse strings to `DateTime?`:

```
public static DateTime? TryGetDateTime(this string item, DateTimeFormatInfo dfi, params string[] allowedFormats)
{
    if (dfi == null) dfi = DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo;
    DateTime dt;
    bool success = DateTime.TryParseExact(item, allowedFormats, dfi, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
    if (success) return dt;
    return null;
}
```

Result is:

```
 08.06.2015 00:00:00    System.DateTime
 22.06.2015 00:00:00    System.DateTime
 26.06.2015 00:00:00    System.DateTime
 26.05.2015 00:00:00    System.DateTime
```

Comment: My mistake about the format, but yes this seems to work amazingly well. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

That roughly looks correct, but you have a start of line and end of line check in your regex (the `^` at the start and the `$` at the end).

Try this: `(\d{1,2})\.(\d{1,2})\.(\d{2,4})`

Comment: This regex will also match `1.2.123` value. Not sure it is expected.

Comment: But what if you have line like this : "000a95.6.153a9 Final.xlsx"

Answer (score 0):

This works with your examples :

```
[a-zA-Z\d\s]+(?:_|\s)(\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{2,4})
```

Demo here : https://regex101.com/r/hA6dQ3/1